# difference between two dates in php or javascript or in jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate the date difference between 2 dates using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-date-difference-between-2-dates-using-php)

Hi,,
i am using dd-mm-yyyy format for date;
can u pls give me the code how to find the difference between two dates?

Comment: The JavaScript aspect makes this a different question, folks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## JavaScript

If you're using a string in the format DD-MM-YYYY for your date values, you have two things you need to do: 1. Convert the string into a date, and 2. Get the difference between the dates. I'll take those in reverse order:

### Date Difference

In JavaScript, performing arithmetic on `Date` instances will use their underlying "time" value (`date.getTime()`), which is the number of milliseconds since The Epoch (and can be negative). So to get the difference, just subtract one date from another:

```
var d1 = new Date(2010, 0, 1); // January 1st 2010
var d2 = new Date(2010, 1, 1); // February 1st 2010
var diff = d2 - d1;            // Milliseconds between the dates (in this case, 2678400000)
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/enose3)

### String to Date

If you have your dates in a string in the form DD-MM-YYYY, you'll have to dice up that string to create the `Date` instances. `String#split` will split up the string using the delimiter you give it (`-` in this case) and create an array of strings, and then `parseInt` will convert those strings into numbers (we specify the radix, in this case `10` for decimal, so that we don't have to worry about `parseInt` seeing a leading `0` and assuming octal):

```
function ddmmyyyyToDate(str) {
    var parts = str.split("-");                  // Gives us ["dd", "mm", "yyyy"]
    return new Date(parseInt(parts[2], 10),      // Year
                    parseInt(parts[1], 10) - 1,  // Month (starts with 0)
                    parseInt(parts[0], 10));     // Day of month
}

var s1 = "01-01-2010";          // January 1st 2010
var d1 = ddmmyyyyToDate(s1);
var s2 = "01-02-2010";          // February 1st 2010
var d2 = ddmmyyyyToDate(s2);
var diff = d2 - d1;
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/enose3/5)

The reason you have to do it yourself is that it's only recently that there was a standard string format you could pass into `new Date()` to have it parse it into a date instance. A standard (a simplified version of [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso8601)) was introduced in the [5th edition spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), but isn't well-supported in the wild yet.

Comment: Sir, its giving as NaN message

Comment: @Kiran: Did you check out the live examples? They're working. I double-checked in IE6, IE8, Firefox, Opera, and Chrome (not that any of this is new, all of the above is supported in every JavaScript implementation I know of).

Comment: Sorry sir,,it is working just i divided by 100*60*60*24;\

Comment: @Kiran: If you want the result in days, it should be 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, not 100 * 60 * 60 * 24. As I said in the answer above, the result is in milliseconds (thousandths of a second).

Comment: @ T.J.Crowder:thank u so much it has been useful for me in many modules thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

```
// php
echo strtotime($date1) - strtotime($date2); // echos the time difference between $date1 and $date2 in seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use php 5.3, you can use the DateTime object:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, take a look at the [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com) library, which makes working with dates in JavaScript easy.  You will need to download the [full package](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/downloads/detail?name=Datejs-all-Alpha1.zip&can=2&q=) which contains globalization modules which affect how dates are parsed and rendered.  With the appropriate CultureInfo file:

```
Date.parse('11-12-2010') - Date.parse('25-12-2010');
```

This statement returns `-1209600000` ms; divide to get other units – `/1000/60/60/24 = -14` days.  (Dividing by `1000` ms, `60` seconds, `60` minutes, `24` hours to get days.